# How to use ext4magic in LVM?

Tags: linux, security, lvm, data-recovery

I'm trying to recover using ext4magic.my partition was LVM.

try to execute command

```
ext4magic /dev/sda1  -J -f -s 2048  imges/
```

error

```
/dev/sda2 Error 2133571347 while opening filesystem 
ext4magic : EXIT_SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the typo (`imges` not `images`) it [looks like](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552544/extundelete-failed-to-read-only-open-device-dev-sdb-error-code-2133571347) that error code means either the superblock is corrupt or not loading correctly.

Do you need to put `imges/` next to the `-f` flag for it to work? And was 2048 definitely your block size?

Otherwise, you could attempt to recreate/recover the LVM partition instead. I've done this once before and it worked well enough to recover data. I believe by default there should be some backup files in `/etc/lvm/backup` with details of the volumes.

Comment: And also can't find my block size!